# Calculate maximum values for three consecutive days of tibble in R

Tags: r

I am doing time series analysis. Part of my data is as follow:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  time                  DOY Value
  <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl>
1 2015-01-08 12:30:00     8 0.664
2 2015-01-08 13:00:00     8 0.647
3 2015-01-11 14:00:00    11 0.669
4 2015-01-11 15:00:00    11 0.644
5 2015-02-04 12:30:00    35 0.664
6 2015-02-04 13:00:00    35 0.647
```

I would like to calculate the maximum values of 7 consecutive days of the data. For example:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  time                  DOY Value Max
  <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2015-01-08 12:30:00     8 0.664 11.669
2 2015-01-08 13:00:00     8 0.647 11.669
3 2015-01-11 14:00:00    11 0.669 11.669
4 2015-01-11 15:00:00    11 0.644 11.669
5 2015-02-04 12:30:00    35 0.664 35.664
6 2015-02-04 13:00:00    35 0.647 35.664
```

Comment: when you say 7 consecutive days, the output showed shows days different

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and in particular show your data using dput(X) where X is the input.  Also code and data should be indented 4 spaces in which case SO will format it for you.

Comment: Thanks for reformatting the data, Heiwa. Ignore the timestamp step below as you provide a proper timestamp already. Can you elaborate what you mean with 7 consecutive days and how you get the Max value in your example. I fail to see how these values are derived from the example.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to R and Stackoverflow. As mentioned above, you will find many friends here, if you provide a reproducible example, and explain what you have done and/or where things go wrong for you. This helps others to help you.

Based on your data fragment, I do some basic operations that I think might help you. Still you may need to adapt the principles to your problem case.

**data**

I turned your example into a tibble. Please note, when you work with date, times, date-times I recommend you use the respective variable type. This will give you access to helpful functions, etc.

Please also note you mentioned 8*3 tibble above. In fact your data structure is already a 4 column tibble with Date, time, DOY, and value!

```
library(dplyr)     # basic dataframe/tibble operations
library(lubridate) # for datetime handling

df <- tribble(
     ~Date,     ~time,   ~DOY, ~Value
    ,"2015-01-08", "12:30:00", 8,  0.664 
    ,"2015-01-08", "13:00:00", 8,  0.647
    ,"2015-01-11", "14:00:00", 11, 0.669
    ,"2015-01-11", "15:00:00", 11, 0.644
    ,"2015-02-04", "12:30:00", 35, 0.664
    ,"2015-02-04", "13:00:00", 35, 0.647
)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(timestamp = ymd_hms(paste(Date, time))
```

This yields:

```
df
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  Date       time       DOY Value timestamp          
  <chr>      <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>             
1 2015-01-08 12:30:00     8 0.664 2015-01-08 12:30:00
2 2015-01-08 13:00:00     8 0.647 2015-01-08 13:00:00
3 2015-01-11 14:00:00    11 0.669 2015-01-11 14:00:00
4 2015-01-11 15:00:00    11 0.644 2015-01-11 15:00:00
5 2015-02-04 12:30:00    35 0.664 2015-02-04 12:30:00
6 2015-02-04 13:00:00    35 0.647 2015-02-04 13:00:00
```

Note: timestamp is now a datetime objet `dttm`.

**binning of data**

It is not fully clear what your consecutive 7 days are and/or how you "group" them.
I assume you want to pick 7 days of a week.
As datetime is dttm, we can use the power of {lubridate} and extract the week from the datetime.

Note: you may want to bin/group your data differently. Think about what you want to achieve here and adpat this accordingly.

```
df <- df %>% mutate(bin = week(timestamp))
df

# A tibble: 6 x 6
  Date       time       DOY Value timestamp             bin
  <chr>      <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>              <dbl>
1 2015-01-08 12:30:00     8 0.664 2015-01-08 12:30:00     2
2 2015-01-08 13:00:00     8 0.647 2015-01-08 13:00:00     2
3 2015-01-11 14:00:00    11 0.669 2015-01-11 14:00:00     2
4 2015-01-11 15:00:00    11 0.644 2015-01-11 15:00:00     2
5 2015-02-04 12:30:00    35 0.664 2015-02-04 12:30:00     5
6 2015-02-04 13:00:00    35 0.647 2015-02-04 13:00:00     5
```

If you want to work on "7 consecutive days" you will need to identify the groups of 7 days. Again, there are different ways to do this, check what the modulo operator does and how to apply this to your DOY.

**operating on your groups/bins**

You describe looking for the maximum per bin (7 days ~ week).
`{dplyr}` offers for such problems `grouped operations`. Read up on them:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(bin) %>% 
  summarise(MaxValue = max(Value)     # we create a new variable and assing the max of each group to it
            )

# A tibble: 2 x 2
    bin MavValue
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1     2    0.669
2     5    0.664
```

Obviously, you can perform many operations (summaries of your bins/groups).

Note: You can create bins on multiple variables. Read up on group_by() and summarise(..., .groups = "drop"), if you want to use this interim tibble for further calculations.

Hope this gets you started.

**clarification on grouping by 7 days**

If you have a sequence of (integer) numbers, there is a neat way to group this into n-element bins, i.e. using integer division.

In your case the data comes already with a date-of-year DOY variable. For completeness: with lubridate you can pull the DOY from a timestamp with the function `yday()`, i.e. (`df %>% mutate(DOY = yday(timestamp))`.

```
# let's use integer division to group our DOYs into group of 7s
##--------- does not look at date or day
##--------- group 1-7 := 0, group 8-14 := 1, .... group 29-35 := 5

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(bin = DOY %/% 7)
```

This yields:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  Date       time       DOY Value timestamp             bin
  <chr>      <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>              <dbl>
1 2015-01-08 12:30:00     8 0.664 2015-01-08 12:30:00     1
2 2015-01-08 13:00:00     8 0.647 2015-01-08 13:00:00     1
3 2015-01-11 14:00:00    11 0.669 2015-01-11 14:00:00     1
4 2015-01-11 15:00:00    11 0.644 2015-01-11 15:00:00     1
5 2015-02-04 12:30:00    35 0.664 2015-02-04 12:30:00     5
6 2015-02-04 13:00:00    35 0.647 2015-02-04 13:00:00     5
```

And then build your max summary as before on the (new) grouping variable:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(bin) %>%
  summarise(MaxValue = max(Value)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
    bin MaxValue
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1    0.669
2     5    0.664
```

For the example data given the result is identical. However, with your full dataset and the offset between "weeks" (with their defined start date) vs cutting your DOYs into bins of 7 consecutive days, you will get a different summary (unless, the first day of the week (*) coincides with DOY 1).

(*): in lubridate you can set weeks to start Monday or Sunday as a parameter (in case you ever need this).

Comment: Dear Ray,
Thanks indeed! 
Actually, I would like to move down continuously. For example, the first 7 days include Day 1 to 7 (Row 1 to 4), and the second 7 days will be from Day 2 to 8, etc.
How could I do for that? 
Thanks again!

Comment: I amended my answer to cater for what is called  an integer division, i.e. %/%, as you can use your DOY (1...365/366) to extract this. Obviously, there are (many) other ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks you, @Ray! Now I got that using lead function as follow: 
Seven_con <- df %>%
  group_by(Yr, Month) %>%
  mutate(MaxValue = max(Value),
         lead_day = lead(DOY, 4),
         lead_Value = lead(Value, 4)) %>%
  mutate(Value_7Ds = if_else(Max_Value > lead_Value, Max_Value, lead_Value))